# Date picker to populate multiple fields on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a datepicker on a form and I want to be able to populate other fields based on the date selected on the date picker. So the other fields are

Month
Year
Quarter

I have found the solution to populate one of these fields. But can I update multiple fields, for example I select the date from datepicker and it populates the month input field and the year and the quarter if possible. I understand the quarter might be a bit more tricky? any help would be great

$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "mmddy",
      altField: "#alternate1",
     altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"

Comment: If you want to set multiple fields, I would think you would need to create a http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose option that takes the (optionally) selected data, and uses that to set the other fields.

Comment: Hi Taplar, I am not sure I fully understand, is this diificult to do? This is my current code for datepicker.$("#date").datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "http://tschvm163/pewsaudit/assets/images/calendar3.gif",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  changeYear: false,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  //showButtonPanel: true,
  //autoClose: true,
  //keepOpen: false,
  //changeMonth: true,
  onSelect: function () {
   $(".ui-datepicker a").removeAttr("href");

  }
 });

Comment: any help with this one?